# Delete Service Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to delete  PostOffices from the array depending on their ID (there will be a checkbox that selectes the desired element and it will use its id for the  delete function ) 
here is the

```
****here is the array 

let postOffices = [
                {postOfficeID: 15, postCode: '3006', postOfficeNameFR:                    'TunisPost', assignedAgentFirstName: 'BEN JEMAA',                       assignedAgentName: 'Radhia', assignedAgentLogin:                          'POABR'},
                {postOfficeID: 16, postCode: '2086', postOfficeNameFR:                    'SoussePost', assignedAgentFirstName: 'SAMTI',                            assignedAgentName: 'Achref', assignedAgentLogin:                          'POASA'}
            ];

 ***here is the delete service that I tried to create 


            deletePostOffice(postOffice:PostOffice)
{

    this.postOffices.splice(this.postOffices.indexOf(this.postOffice.postOfficeID),1);
}
```

Comment: You need to read the documentation of indexOf(), realize that it's not the method you should use, then find for another method that would do what you want, and read the documentation of findIndex(). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any easy way would just be to use the JavaScript array `.filter()` method to compare the `postOfficeID` property, and/or any other property you want to filter by.

**Example #1:**

```
  deletePostOffice(postOffice: PostOffice): void {
      this.postOffices = this.postOffices.filter((_office: PostOffice) => {
        // Return false (e.g. do NOT filter this object out) if the Ids don't match
        return (_office.postOfficeID !== postOffice.postOfficeID);
      });
  }
```

[**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NqFE5G5f89h5gY0EE2wk?p=preview)

You can read more about JavaScript the `.filter()` method, as well as supported browsers, on the [MDN Documentation Page for `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

> The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass
>   the test implemented by the provided function.

I'm re-assigning `this.postOffices = this.postOffices.filter(...)` because:

> `filter()` does not mutate the array on which it is called.

**Note:** I changed your type from `PostOffice` to `any` for the Plnkr because I'm lazy and didn't want to rebuild the model for the example, but it should work either way. :)

**UPDATE**

To answer the second part of Narjes Ben Slimen's question and to further illustrate the usage of the `.filter()` method with a "delete queue":

> "There will be a checkbox next to each element of the array what should
>   I do so this delete function works only on the selected elements ?
>   should I add something to the button?" -OP

A "delete" queue can be created that stores off the objects/ids for a later time when the user decides to "remove" them from the list. The filter method can then be used, in conjunction with a child looping mechanism, to remove item(s) from the primary list based on it's existence in the delete queue.

**Example #2:**

```
  deletePostOffices(): void {
      this.postOffices = this.postOffices.filter((_office: any) => {
        // Typing this long-hand for easier understanding
        let _keep = true;

        this.deleteQueue.forEach((_deleteOffice: any) => {
          if (_office.postOfficeID === _deleteOffice.postOfficeID) {
            _keep = false;
          }
        });

        return _keep;
      });

      // Clear the queue because the 'deleted' post offices no longer exist
      this.deleteQueue = [];
  }
```

**[Working Plnker For Example 2](http://plnkr.co/edit/ULKKQthP3y6wBQszDISo?p=preview)**

Comment: There will be a checkbox next to each element of the array what should I do so this delete function works only on the selected elements ? should I add something to the button ?

Comment: @NarjesBenSlimen You'll need to add some sort of 'delete queue' to store off the saved post office object/ids until which time the user chooses to delete them. Then inside the `.filter()` method you can loop through the queue and remove accordingly.  Here is a Plnkr example to get you started: http://plnkr.co/edit/ULKKQthP3y6wBQszDISo?p=preview